# How to create a Account in Salesforce Using Developer Console with Postman

Tags: rest-api

With Out Using apex class, How to create a Account Record Using in Postman, in Postman using How to create a Record in Account Object with out Wrighting any class. can you please give me any suggestions..

Comment: Please go through the [ask] section to leverage the most out of this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for. Use REST API resources to create, retrieve, update, and delete records, along with other record-related operations.Please go through below Salesforce document -

[Create a Record](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_create.htm)

Comment: How to create a Event use REST API resources ...

Answer (score 2):

Answering your following question:

> **How to create a Record in Account Object with out Writing any class?**

There is a [Trailhead Challenge](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trails/force_com_dev_intermediate/modules/api_basics/units/api_basics_rest) for this. 
Please go through that challenge and you should be able to do this.

You need to perform following steps as mentioned in Trailhead using [Workbench](http://workbench.developerforce.com/restExplorer.php):

> Create an Account
>
> Now let’s create an account using the SObject resource and the POST
>   method. In the URI text box, replace the existing text with
>   /services/data/vXX.0/sobjects/account, where XX maps to the API
>   version you’re using. Select POST. Notice that a Request Body text
>   area appears, which is where we specify the field values for our new
>   account. First, though, let’s change the Accept header back to JSON.

In the request body, enter the following text.

```
{
  "Name" : "NewAccount1",
  "ShippingCity" : "San Francisco"
}
```